# Dynamic allowed types in PrimeFaces fileUpload

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

My allowedTypes in PrimeFaces p:fileUpload are not static.They depend on some parameter which is passed as request parameter to the page. So how to change allowedTypes dynamically according to that request parameter.

Comment: If you know what the parameters will be, `allowTypes` supports regular expression for accepted file types http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_0.pdf

Comment: It depends on a single request parameter named 'signmethod' which can be accessed like #{param.signmethod}. This parameter can have as many as 17 different values and so there can be 17 different allowed file types for that page depending on what value is passed in that parameter.

Comment: have you tried  <p:fileUpload ... allowTypes="#{yourbean.signmethod}" /> where signmethod returns a string containing the correct regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried it with defining the allowedTypes via a bean property and that is working for me.
So define a allowedTypes property in you bean

```
public String getAllowedTypes() {
    return "/(gif|png)$/";
}
```

and call it in your page

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadView.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false"
       update="rocomessages" sizeLimit="100000" fileLimit="3" allowTypes="#{fileUploadView.allowedTypes}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another idea. Create a String function with parameter(s), this can be used when the types must be dynamics.

This could be the String function in your Bean:

```
public String getAllowedTypes(String someData) {
  if (value.equals("My special types")) {
    return "/(\\.|\\/)(json)$/";
  }
  return "/(\\.|\\/)(ZIP|zip)$/";
}
```

and, like this, you call ir in the page:

```
<p:fileUpload allowTypes="#{MyBean.allowedTypes(MyBean.anotherString)}" />
```

Note: you can use Switch instead of IF in getAllowedTypes function, this must be understand for another uses.